# Symfony Serializer XML Attribute

Tags: xml, symfony, serialization

I want to use the Symfony XML Serializer to transform a class instance (not an array). So for example I want to create an XML like so with the attribute myAtt="foo" ,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<REQ>
    <TravelAgencySender myAtt="foo">
        <CityName>town</CityName>
        <AgencyID>agency</AgencyID>
    </TravelAgencySender>   
</REQ>
```

So I have created a class like so

```
class TravelAgencySender 
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private  $CityName;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public  $AgencyID;
.....
}
```

And the following initialization

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\MetadataAwareNameConverter;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Loader\AnnotationLoader;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;



$classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));

$metadataAwareNameConverter = new MetadataAwareNameConverter($classMetadataFactory);

$serializer = new Serializer(
    [new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, $metadataAwareNameConverter)],
    ['json' => new JsonEncoder(), 'xml' => new XmlEncoder()]
);
```

Does anyone know how to add the myAtt attribute?

Thanks

And this produces the below XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<REQ>
    <TravelAgencySender>
        <CityName>town</CityName>
        <AgencyID>agency</AgencyID>
    </TravelAgencySender>   
</REQ>
```

Comment: Move on to JMSSerializer Bundle if you can. An example with attribute is [here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/oxlj/validating-serialising-and-mapping-xml-request-to-model-classes).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use SerializedName as follows:

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;
    
class TravelAgencySender 
    {
        /**
         * @SerializedName("@myAtt")
         * @var string
         */
        private  $foo;
        /**
         * @var string
        */
        private  $CityName;
        /**
         * @var string
         */
        public  $AgencyID;
    .....
    }
```

Comment: How do you do this via Annotations or PHP Attributes on the root node though?

Answer (score 0):

The array keys beginning with @ are considered XML attributes:

```
['foo' => ['@bar' => 'value']];
```

is encoded as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
     <foo bar="value"/>
</response>
```

Comment: Is not an array. Is an object. Your comment doesn't make any sense.